# why does css position:fixed not work for the dialog tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm starting to make a cookie banner. Simplifying my problem as much as possible, I pasted the following in the w3schools tryit editor:

```
<dialog open style="position:fixed;right:0;">
  <button>Decline</button>&nbsp;
  <button>Allow cookies</button>
</dialog>
```

expected result: it should go to the right of the viewport. Actual result: the dialog is centered in the viewport.

When I edit the above to use div instead of dialog it works as expected:

```
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;">
  <button>Decline</button>&nbsp;
  <button>Allow cookies</button>
</div>
```

goes to the right of the viewport as it should do.

How can I get this behaviour from the HTML5 dialog tag?

Thanks for all the good work people are doing here.

Comment: Inspect *dialog*: its browser-default styles - chrome gives its `margin:auto` so it's centered. Try `margin:0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* for testing */
  min-height: 200vh;
}

dialog {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin: unset;
  inset-inline-start: unset;
}
```

```html
<dialog open>
  <button>Decline</button>&nbsp;<button>Allow cookies</button>
</dialog>
```

In fact, you can get away with `right: 0;`, because browser styles have `inset-inline-end: 0;`. But I am not 100% sure that all browsers have it.

Comment: thank you imhvost. The user agent stylesheet does indeed set inset-inline-start:0; overruling that with auto or unset fixes the problem.